# how would first and second derivative help find the inflection point and local max/min?

Tags: calculus

A brand new stock is also called an initial public offering, or IPO. Remember that, in this model, the period immediately after the stock is issued offers excess returns on the stock – that is, the stock is selling for more than it is really worth. One such model for a class of internet IPOs predicts the percent overvaluation of a stock as a function of time as $$R(t)= \frac{9t(t-4)^3}{2.718},$$ where $R(t)$ is the overvaluation in percent and $t$ is the time in months after the initial issue.

By using the first derivative and second derivative, how would we know when to buy or sell (inflexion point) and the exact time to buy or sell (local max/min), and any false signals. How can you use derivatives to determine this? Also what would the sketch look like for the original function, first and second derivative?

I know how to find derivatives however i don't know how this would help find the inflection point and the local max/min and how you would connect this to find out when to buy and sell.

Comment: If the stock is sold at a high price, how dare we say it is not worth the price that some other people are willing to pay?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to MSE. Your post will be better received if you have shown us what you have tried, or what your motivation behind the question is!

Answer (score 0):

- An inflection point occurs when the second derivative of a function is equal to $0$. It shows the point at which, for example, the **slope** of a function changes from increasing to decreasing. To find it, in your case, you just equal the second derivative of $R(t)$ to $0$. From then you can solve for $t$, your inflection point.
  $$
  \dfrac{\mathrm{d}^2R(t)}{\mathrm{d}x}=0
  $$
- A max/min likewise occurs when the first derivative is equal to $0$. It shows the point at which, for example, the **function** (the values of $R(t)$) changes from increasing to decreasing. To find it, you equal the first derivative of $R(t)$ to $0$. From then you can solve for $t$, your max/min.
  $$
  \dfrac{\mathrm{d}R(t)}{\mathrm{d}x}=0
  $$
  If you want to find out whether your max/min is a max or a min you must evaluate the second derivative of the function at the value for $t$ obtained from the previous expression. If the second derivative is greater than $0$, that means your max/min is actually a min. If the second derivative is less than $0$, that means your max/min is a max.

[This is the graph for the original function, and for the first and second derivatives.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ua0oehpb7j)

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the graph of the function, when the first derivative is set equal to zero and solved for t, this gives the  times when the original function was at a max or a min. The second derivative when set equal to zero and solved for t gives the time when the rate of change of the overvaluation was a maximum, either increasing or decreasing.